# search array and get array key

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

I have an array, which I'd like to search for a value in and retreive the array key if it exists, but not sure how to even go about doing that. Here's my array:

```
Array
(
    [hours] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 10
        )
)
```

So I'd like to search the hours array for 10, if 10 exists in the array, I want the key (5) to be returned. If that makes sense?

Am trying to do it dynamically so the search string (10) will change, but I figure if I can get it working for number 10, I can get it working with a variable number :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**array_search**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is what you need.

```
$var = 10;
$key = array_search($var, $hours);
```

Comment: Not sure the second example is any more useful than just calling array_search directly?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $key = array_search($array, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$key = array_search(10,$aray); // $key will get 5 in your case.
```

the syntax is:

```
key = array_search(value_to_search,array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Syntax : array_search ( Search Keyword here , Array here);  

$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red

$key = array_search('green', $array);   // $key = 2;

$key = array_search('red', $array);  // $key = 1
```

Comment: This question already had an accepted answer more than 6 years ago. Your answer only provides a guide on how to use array_search, rather than adapting it to the question's data. Please only add alternative answers to long-dead questions when they provide a new approach that **improves** upon the accepted answer.